# Kafka Streams DSL Suppress Action Seems Doesn't Work

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I followed the official 
[link](https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#window-final-results), but don't **get exactly one final window final results**.

I have tried stable version 2.2.0 and 2.1.0, This has happened. someone said there is some know bugs in suppress() and has been fixed, but I can't find the bug's location. can anyone paste a link?

there is my java code

```
        kstreams[0]
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("--> ping, k={},v={}", k, v))
                .groupBy((k, v) -> v, Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(100)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(20)))
                .count()
                .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
                .toStream().peek((k, v) -> log.info("window={},k={},v={}", k.window(), k.key(), v));
```

there is my log

```
2019-04-24 20:00:26.142  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:00:47.070  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556106587744, endMs=1556107129191},k=A,v=20
2019-04-24 20:00:51.071  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:01:16.065  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:01:41.066  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:02:06.069  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:02:31.066  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:02:56.208  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:03:21.070  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:03:46.078  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:04:04.684  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:04:11.069  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:04:19.371  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107426409},k=B,v=9
2019-04-24 20:04:19.372  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107445012},k=A,v=1
2019-04-24 20:04:29.604  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:04:36.067  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:04:49.715  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107451397},k=B,v=10
2019-04-24 20:04:49.716  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107469935},k=A,v=2
2019-04-24 20:04:54.593  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:05:01.070  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:05:19.599  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:05:20.045  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107476398},k=B,v=11
2019-04-24 20:05:20.047  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107501398},k=B,v=12
2019-04-24 20:05:26.075  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:05:44.598  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:05:50.399  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107519930},k=A,v=4
2019-04-24 20:05:50.400  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107526405},k=B,v=13
2019-04-24 20:05:51.067  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:06:09.595  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:06:16.089  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:06:20.765  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107544929},k=A,v=5
2019-04-24 20:06:20.767  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107569926},k=A,v=6
2019-04-24 20:06:34.595  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:06:41.063  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:06:51.081  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107576415},k=B,v=15
2019-04-24 20:06:51.082  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107594925},k=A,v=7
2019-04-24 20:06:59.607  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:07:06.072  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:07:21.440  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107601391},k=B,v=16
2019-04-24 20:07:21.441  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107619935},k=A,v=8
2019-04-24 20:07:24.596  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:07:31.066  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:07:49.608  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:07:51.775  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107626420},k=B,v=17
2019-04-24 20:07:51.777  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107651396},k=B,v=18
2019-04-24 20:07:56.064  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:08:14.591  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:08:21.066  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:08:22.125  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107669943},k=A,v=10
2019-04-24 20:08:22.126  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107694921},k=A,v=11
2019-04-24 20:08:39.619  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:08:46.067  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:08:52.457  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107701397},k=B,v=20
2019-04-24 20:08:52.458  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107719949},k=A,v=12
2019-04-24 20:09:04.599  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=A
2019-04-24 20:09:11.066  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : --> ping, k=4,v=B
2019-04-24 20:09:22.794  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107226473, endMs=1556107726398},k=B,v=21   
2019-04-24 20:09:22.796  INFO --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.k.AppStreams                        : window=Window{startMs=1556107445012, endMs=1556107744928},k=A,v=13
```

It seems i got a **window final result** per record.

Comment: My source stream record rate is  a same v record / 25s, gap of inactivity is 100s, 25<100. I shouldn't got so many window info print log. Session window close and then reopened? my grace is 20 millisecond, it should not be ah.

Comment: The bug fixes are in the 2.2 branch (https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/2.2). You need to check out the branch and build the packages yourself. Instructions can be found in the README file on the branch.

Comment: I have tried build the branch, and upgraded my broker and stream application, the same log print, it seems doesn't work. I build the branch and run **./gradlew installAll** to my local maven repository, then use it from my local maven. the suffix is **2.2.1-SNAPSHOT**. the broker come from **./gradlew clean releaseTarGz** . Any idea?

Comment: Seems you are hitting: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8289 -- that is not fixed yet.